# Cannot upload select photos with Cyberduck

Tags: static, ftp, hosting, static-site, cyberduck

I'm currently using Cyberduck to get my static site up and running. The only issue I'm running into is being able to host 2 of my 5 images on my website.

The following 3 images **will** host:

- iphone.png - 57 KB
- macmoc.png - 61 KB
- resume.pdf - 106 KB

And these two **will not**:

- me.JPG - 1.2 MB
- zenBG-1.png - 516 KB

I checked the permissions on each image and they are all the same: rw-r--r-- (644). From typing this out it looks like the file sizes might be too large, but I've waited well over 18 hours and still these images will not host. The images are displayed when running on localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered. Turns out that while running images locally, the file names are not case sensitive, however when using cyberduck they are.

Conclusion: Make sure to name your files exactly as they are referenced in your HTML.